# Cannot find a symbol error in java when compiling from command prompt

Tags: java, java-8

Hi I have created two Java file under a directory called Utility with as follow:

1. FileName.java

> ```
> public class FileName {
>   private String name;
>   public FileName (String name) {
>       //some code
>   }
>   String getName() {
>       return name;
>   }
> }
> ```

2. FileNameReader.java

> ```
> public class FileNameReader {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
>       FileName obj = new FileName("testfile.txt");
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Now, when i am comipling throw command prompt, compiler giving me error saying cannot file symbol at FileName obj = new FileName(); this line

Comment: Don't fix your code afterwards because it completely changes the context of the question. Right now, there shouldn't be any compiler error anymore, except for the missing import statement.

Comment: @QBrute, I've deleted my answer because it does not make sense anymore

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public SearchFile(String name) {
```

That would be the constructor of a class called SearchFile.

But your class is named FileName; so you have have to rename everything (class and file name) to SearchFile; or you change the ctor to say `public FileName(String name)` instead.

Beyond that: that class **only** has a constructor taking a string argument. But your other class goes for `new FileName()` without providing an argument. That will not work either.

But the real answer here: such "subtle" details matter. You have to pay **close** attention to each and any line of code that you write down. And: you run the compiler immediately after you have "finished" something of which you think it should compile. You don't create 2, 3 files with 10, 20, 50 lines of code to then find out that you have a bunch of problems in each file!

Comment: Probably you have many different errors. Go file by file, start with those that don't depend on others.

Answer (score 0):

You have to problems in your `FileNameReader` class:

1. You need to import the `IOException` by adding

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   ```
2. You have created an explicit constructor for `FileName` with a `String` argument, so the implicit default constructor is no longer visible. You need to provide that `String` when creating a new instance:

   ```
   FileName obj = new FileName("someString");
   ```

This FileNameReader.java compiles:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileNameReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      FileName obj = new FileName("someString");
  }

}
```